# jQuery - Ajax sucess parameter as object function

Tags: jquery

jQuery - ajax success parameter
i wanna know how to give a object method (function), on the success parameter, to the ajax function (sorry for my english)

lets say i already set my ajax.setup with all i need to call a php on the server.

```
function myClass(id)
{
  this.id = id;

  this.showValues=function(xml) 
  {
    alert(this.id); // to prove we r in the right object
    alert(typeof(xml)); // to prove we got the xml     
  };

  this.retrieveValues=function()
  { 
    // wont call the method, this is just text, like writing sucess:"hello"
    $.ajax({success: this.id+'.showValues'}); 


   // calls the method but this.id is undefined (xml is received tho)
    $.ajax({success: this.showValues}); 


    // wont call the method
    $.ajax({success: new Function(this.id+'.showValues')}); 


    // calls the method with the right id but xml is undefined
    $.ajax({success: new Function(this.id+'.showValues()')}); 


    // js error - "xml not defined"
    $.ajax({success: new Function(this.id+'.showValues(xml)')}); 


    // of course, next line works, but i dont wanna define the function here
     $.ajax({success: function() { alert(this.id); alert(typeof(xml)); } });    

  };

}


// even declaring the object as global, so the class has a chance to call a method using the var name
// wich is this.id+'.retrieveValues' ==> object1.retrieveValues
var object1;

function Main() // main =d
{
  object1 = new myClass('object1');
  object1.retrieveValues();

}
```

again, sorry for my bad english .. learning still =d
i hope someone can help me, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found it using Function api help <_< i was missing the "xml" parameter

```
$.ajax({success: new Function("xml",this.id+'.showValues(xml)')});
```

new Function("xml",this.id+'.showValues(xml)') is like saying

function(xml) 
   { object1.showValues(xml); 
   }

thanks dedoz.
no problem. =D